# Display division calculation result in an HTML5 / AngularJS input

Tags: angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, angularjs-1.6

I have a conflict between ng-if and ng-options.

The function montantAnnuel() works well without ng-if, but when I use ng-if to show a group of 2 inputs, then it does not work anymore.

App.js :

```
var SupportDemandeApp = angular.module('SupportDemandeApp', ['ngMessages']);

SupportDemandeApp.controller('SupportDemandeCtrl', ['$scope', SupportDemandeCtrl]);

function SupportDemandeCtrl($scope) {

$scope.typeContrat = function () {
    $scope.types = ['Niv.I - Impartition IMS',
                    'Niv.II - Impartition TMA / AMS',
                    'Niv.III - Projet',
                    'Niv.IV - Impartition BPO',
                    'Multi - Tiers avec Impartition',
                    'Multi-Tiers CS & Projet',
                    'Vente de licence ou produit sans services ni modification'];
    $scope.selectedTypeContrat = {};
};

$scope.matchSelectedTypeContrat = function () {
    if (($scope.selectedTypeContrat.type == 'Niv.I - Impartition IMS') ||
        ($scope.selectedTypeContrat.type == 'Niv.II - Impartition TMA / AMS') ||
        ($scope.selectedTypeContrat.type == 'Niv.IV - Impartition BPO') ||
        ($scope.selectedTypeContrat.type == 'Multi-Tiers avec Impartition'))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
};

$scope.inputMontantAnnuel = 0;

$scope.montantAnnuel = function () {
    if (angular.isUndefined($scope.inputMontantGlobalAffaire) && angular.isUndefined($scope.inputDureeAnnee)) {
        $scope.inputMontantAnnuel = 0;
    }
    else if (angular.isUndefined($scope.inputDureeAnnee)) {
        $scope.inputMontantAnnuel = $scope.inputMontantGlobalAffaire;
    }
    else if ($scope.inputMontantGlobalAffaire && $scope.inputDureeAnnee) {
        $scope.inputMontantAnnuel = ($scope.inputMontantGlobalAffaire / $scope.inputDureeAnnee);
    }
};
}
```

Index.cshtml :

```
<div ng-app="App" ng-controller="Ctrl">
<form class="form-horizontal" id="supportDemandeForm" name="supportDemandeForm" method="post" ng-submit="validationSupportDemande(supportDemandeForm.$valid)" novalidate>
    <fieldset>
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': supportDemandeForm.inputMontantGlobalAffaire.$touched && supportDemandeForm.inputMontantGlobalAffaire.$invalid }">
                <label for="inputMontantGlobalAffaire" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Montant global prévu de l'affaire (en K€)<span style="color:red"> *</span></label>
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="inputMontantGlobalAffaire" name="inputMontantGlobalAffaire" ng-model="inputMontantGlobalAffaire" ng-change="montantAnnuel()" pattern="[0-9]+(\\.[0-9][0-9]?)?" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="right" data-content="Build + RUN + Infrastructure" required>
                    <div class="help-block" ng-messages="supportDemandeForm.inputMontantGlobalAffaire.$error" ng-if="supportDemandeForm.inputMontantGlobalAffaire.$touched"><div ng-message="required">Champ requis</div></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': supportDemandeForm.selectTypeContrat.$touched && supportDemandeForm.selectTypeContrat.$invalid }">
                <label for="selectTypeContrat" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Type de contrat (IS/OS)<span style="color:red"> *</span></label>
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                    <select class="form-control" id="selectTypeContrat" name="selectTypeContrat" ng-model="selectedTypeContrat.type" ng-init="typeContrat()" ng-change="montantAnnuel()" ng-options="type for type in types" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="right" data-content="Voir définitions dans l'onglet Type de contrat" required></select>
                    <div class="help-block" ng-messages="supportDemandeForm.selectTypeContrat.$error" ng-if="supportDemandeForm.selectTypeContrat.$touched"><div ng-message="required">Champ requis</div></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group check-element" ng-if="matchSelectedTypeContrat()==true" ng-class="{ 'has-error': supportDemandeForm.inputDureeAnnee.$touched && supportDemandeForm.inputDureeAnnee.$invalid }">
                <div>
                    <label for="inputDureeAnnee" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Durée (en années)<span style="color:red"> *</span></label>
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="inputDureeAnnee" name="inputDureeAnnee" placeholder="" ng-model="inputDureeAnnee" ng-change="montantAnnuel()" required>
                        <div class="help-block" ng-messages="supportDemandeForm.inputDureeAnnee.$error" ng-if="supportDemandeForm.inputDureeAnnee.$touched"><div ng-message="required">Champ requis</div></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <label for="inputMontantAnnuel" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Montant annuel (en K€)</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                        <input readonly type="number" class="form-control" id="inputMontantAnnuel" name="inputMontantAnnuel" ng-model="inputMontantAnnuel" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do ? This is not clear ? Do you want to call the function when you display the div ?

Comment: I'm trying to make appear the group-form <div> formed by the 2 labels-inputs when I choose an option from the options mentionned in the ng-options.

Comment: Can you log selectedTypeContrat.type on ng-change ?

Comment: I believe that the error is in the $scope of montantAnnuel(), because when I apply ng-if and I choose an option that shows the 2 labels-inputs, the $scope doesn't update its value ... or something like that.

Comment: How can I log on ng-change ? where can I put console.log(); ?

Comment: Look my answer, you can add ng-change on your select

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to to call the function montantAnnuel() when I display the div.

Comment: Ok then, I updated my answer, don't forget the ng-change on the select =)

Comment: It does not really work, I do not have the result of the division in inputMontantAnnual. I updated the source code above to see the new changes (App.js & Index.cshtml).

Comment: Initialise tes variables inputDureeAnnee et inputMontantGlobalAffaire au même endroit que $scope.inputMontantAnnuel = 0;. Fais attention à tes conditions, ne divise pas par 0. Tu n'as aucune erreur dans la console ?

Comment: Je pense que le problème est dans la fonction montantAnnuel(), j'ai mis pleins de logs dans chaque condition (if), mais ça m'affiche rien dans la console : il n'accède pas aux conditions ! (il accède à la fonction, mais pas aux conditions if ), alors que quand je mets ng-if en commentaire, la fonction fonctionne très bien.

Comment: J'ai utilisé ng-show à la place, ça fonctionne sur le fiddle en lien sur ma réponse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to init your variables and call `ng-change` on select:

```
$scope.inputDureeAnnee = 0;
$scope.inputMontantGlobalAffaire = 0;

<select class="form-control" id="selectTypeContrat" name="selectTypeContrat" ng-model="selectedTypeContrat.type" ng-init="typeContrat()" ng-options="type for type in types" required ng-change="montantAnnuel()"> </select>
```

Because when you display the div or update your fields, you might be trying to perform an operation on `undefined` values.

Other things:

- instead of `isNaN`, use `angular.isUndefined`,
- instead of `ng-if="selectedTypeContrat.type == 'Niv.I - Impartition IMS' || selectedTypeContrat.type == 'Niv.II - Impartition TMA / AMS' || selectedTypeContrat.type == 'Niv.IV - Impartition BPO' || selectedTypeContrat.type == 'Multi-Tiers avec Impartition'"`, use a function: `ng-if="matchSelectedType()"`, where this function proceed the test and returns `true` or `false`

Or you could also do this but your model won't reflect the initial value (you will have to access it like this: `selectedTypeContrat.type.name`):

```
$scope.types = [
        {name: 'Niv.I - Impartition IMS', displayDiv: true},
        {name: 'Niv.II - Impartition TMA / AMS', displayDiv: true},
        {name: 'Niv.III - Projet', displayDiv: false},
        {name: 'Niv.IV - Impartition BPO', displayDiv: true},
        {name: 'Multi - Tiers avec Impartition', displayDiv: true},
        {name: 'Multi-Tiers CS & Projet', displayDiv: false},
        {name: 'Vente de licence ou produit sans services ni modification', displayDiv: false}
    ];


<select class="form-control" id="selectTypeContrat" name="selectTypeContrat" ng-model="selectedTypeContrat.type" ng-init="typeContrat()" ng-options="type as type.name for type in types" required></select>

ng-if="selectedTypeContrat.type && selectedTypeContrat.type.displayDiv  === true"
```

Finally got this working, see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bhpdm1ba/)
Had to use `ng-show` instead of `ng-if`

Comment: I tried all this, but it doesn't work.  
I believe that the error is in the $scope of montantAnnuel(), because when I apply ng-if and I choose an option that shows the 2 labels-inputs, the $scope doesn't update is value ... something like that.

Comment: THAAAAAAAANK YOU A LOOOOT <3  IT FINALLY WORKS ! 2 jours pour cette ng-show de merde :(

Answer (score 0):

Small improvement in montantAnnuel() :

```
$scope.montantAnnuel = function () {
    if (angular.isUndefined($scope.inputMontantGlobalAffaire))
        $scope.inputMontantAnnuel = 0;
    else if (angular.isUndefined($scope.inputDureeAnnee)) {
        $scope.inputMontantAnnuel = $scope.inputMontantGlobalAffaire;
    } else {
        $scope.inputMontantAnnuel = ($scope.inputMontantGlobalAffaire / $scope.inputDureeAnnee);
    }
};
```